# Map<ID, Set<String>> Loop Question

Tags: apex, map, loop

I have a

```
Map<Id,Set<String>>
```

In my code.

I have a loop structured as this:

```
for(value : data) {

     for(String string : Map.get(value) {

       //Do something
   }
}
```

When I do this am I actually looping through the strings within the Set or is it simply returning the sets themselves  as a string. But not like when I do something like this:

```
Set<String> TestSet = new Set<String>();
TestSet = Map.Get(somevalue)
```

Might be an obvious answer but I can't seem to find any confirmation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that snippet you're looping through the Set's elements.
You could take a look at documentation about [for loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_lists.htm).

```
for (variable : list_or_set) {
        code_block
}
```

> When executing this type of for loop, the Apex runtime engine assigns `variable` to each element in `list_or_set`, and runs the `code_block` for each value.

By the way, I would suggest to always check the result of `map.get()` before iterating over it, unless you're 100% sure there is an element paired with that key.
Doing `for(String string : Map.get(value)) {` will expose to a NullPointerException: if the map doesn't cointains that key, it will return `null` leading to a NPE.
A safer option would be:

```
Set<String> variable = Map.get(value);
if (variable != null) {
    for (String s : variable) {
        do something
    }
}
```

This way your code is more robust and will not raise a NullPointerException.